# How do Iterators work on a List in C++?

Tags: c++, list, listiterator

This is a confusion that I have about how iterators work on a list in C++. Please correct me if I am wrong.

A list (in C++) under the hood is a double linked list. We know the structure of a doubly linked list-a data area and a pointer to the next and previous nodes. So every node in a doubly linked list has an address in the memory. When we declare an iterator on the on a list, it points to this address. So when we derefence an iterator, how is it that we get only the data value?

Comment: *"when we derefence an iterator, how is it that we get only the data value"* because that is how the iterator's dereference operator is defined

Comment: Nag, nag, nag... List is typically implemented as a doubly linked list but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the iterator has overloaded operator * so that it returns a reference to the *value* and not the *node*.

Answer (score 10):

The iterator's dereference operator is simply defined to return (a reference to) the value contained in the node. For example it could be defined like this:

```
template<T>
T& list<T>::iterator::operator *() {
  return this->node_pointer->value;
}
```